# Retrieving ad URLs

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the ad URLs for this website.
http://www.quiltingboard.com/resources/

What I want to do is probably write a script to continuously refresh the page and grab the ad URLs.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup alone isn't going to cut it.  The ads are injected via javascript ( they're doubleclick ads ).

Your options are:

- script something like selenium to look for the urls 10-15seconds after page load
- if you stay in pure python, you'll need to :

  1. make the initial request to parse with beautiful soup
  2. figure out what google was going to inject with javascript
  3. make a secondary request to doubleclick for the iframe or payload url

Those methods will only get you the doubleclick urls that handle conversion tracking.  If you want to find out where they redirect to, you'll need to open those urls to discover their redirects.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there would be a way to get the urls without opening it.

Comment: If DFP directly serves up the ad to one of it's clients, there is often an "adurl=xyz" query param. The problem is that there could be traded traffic for that spot through another network - so that adurl would redirect to a different ad network, which would then redirect to the end url -- or have a few more redirects in there.

You could try that if your use cases allow - but you're still going to need to interact with the DFP server to figure out what ad is being placed in the various ad slots.

Comment: I should also add that you don't need to scrape the site - once you figure out what Google is doing ( use firebug or similar ), you can just start querying the DFP server or making a simpler page that just contains the DFP ad slots and passes in the google account credentials.

Answer (score 0):

[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the textual ads at the top of the screen.

You won't be able to directly use a Python parsing library for this because these links are loaded in using JavaScript after the page has loaded.

One option would be to use a tool like [selenium](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) that allows you to load a page in a browser. Once you have done that you can use BeautifulSoup to scan for the links you are looking for:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)    
ads_div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'ads'})
if ads_div:
    for link in ads_div.find_all('a'):
        print link['href']
```

Comment: The ads changes from textual as well as banner ads for both the right side and the top.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).

It's a web scraping library.  It allows you to crawl and scrape information from websites quite easily.  The link above is to the official tutorial, which contains lots of sample code, including something that straddles the line of what it appears you need.

Simple scraping according to the site:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "dmoz"
   allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
   start_urls = [
       "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
       "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
   ]

   def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
       items = []
       for site in sites:
           item = DmozItem()
           item['title'] = site.select('a/text()').extract()
           item['link'] = site.select('a/@href').extract()
           item['desc'] = site.select('text()').extract()
           items.append(item)
       return items
```

That's a minor example of using the library to scrape links, which yields:

> [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200
>   http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/>
>        {'desc': [u' - By David Mertz; Addison Wesley. Book in progress, full text, ASCII format. Asks for feedback. [author website, Gnosis
>   Software, Inc.\n],
>         'link': [u'http://gnosis.cx/TPiP/'],
>         'title': [u'Text Processing in Python']} [dmoz] DEBUG: Scraped from <200
>   http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/>
>        {'desc': [u' - By Sean McGrath; Prentice Hall PTR, 2000, ISBN 0130211192, has CD-ROM. Methods to build XML applications fast, Python
>   tutorial, DOM and SAX, new Pyxie open source XML processing library.
>   [Prentice Hall PTR]\n'],
>         'link': [u'http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0130211192'],
>         'title': [u'XML Processing with Python']}

Pretty cool.